# Using Gulp-babel and getting "Argument name clash in strict mode"

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs, gulp-babel

[image]

I'm trying to use **[gulp-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel)** so I can start writing some ES6 / ES2015 code inside of my ES5 app.

```
var gulp          = require('gulp'),
    gutil         = require('gulp-util'),
    gulpif        = require('gulp-if'),
    uglify        = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
    sass          = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    streamqueue   = require('streamqueue'),
    sourcemaps    = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    htmlReplace   = require('gulp-html-replace'),
    runSequence   = require('run-sequence'),
    stripDebug    = require('gulp-strip-debug'),
    del           = require('del'),
    es            = require('event-stream'),
    webpack       = require('webpack-stream'),
    babel         = require('gulp-babel'),
    browserSync   = require('browser-sync').create();
```

And lower down in my code, here is where the problem lies:

```
gulp.task('build-min-bundle', function() {
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.blue.bold(' Compiled bundle file contains these modules:'));
    for (var i=0; i<paths.scripts.length; i++) {
        gutil.log(gutil.colors.yellow.bold('  '+paths.scripts[i]));
    }
    return gulp.src(paths.bundle)
    .pipe(stripDebug())
    .pipe(concat(dist))
    .pipe(babel()) // <--
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', errorlog)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/js'));
});
```

I originally tried this first:

```
.pipe(babel({
    presets: ['es2015']
}))
```

> Argument name clash in strict mode (2774:5)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error isn't in your quoted code, it's on line 2774 of `tickertags.bundle.min.js`. Babel isn't the problem, Babel is **reporting** the problem.

In strict mode, this is an error:

```
function foo(a, a) {
}
```

Note that `a` has been used as an argument name twice. That's valid loose code, but not valid strict code. That's what the error message is telling you about.

[Here's the error](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%22use%20strict%22%3B%0Afunction%20foo(a%2C%20a)%20%7B%0A%7D) replicated in Babel's REPL.

Here's the error replicated in your browser, if your browser correctly supports strict mode:

```js
"use strict";
function foo(a, a) {
}
```

On Chrome, the error is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Duplicate parameter name not allowed in this context

Comment: Thanks! That was it! hehe now I'm getting a new error for a new question: `[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of`

Comment: @LeonGaban: :-) That's just a warning. Basically, the output file's big, so it gave up on styling it. Nothing to worry about (unless you intend hand-editing the resulting file.).