# passing through 2 same parameters in mapstatetoprops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, destructor

I have this in my `mapstatetoprops` function:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({
    currencies: {
        charge: {
            amount,
            recurring: { amount },
        },
    },
})
```

so when I pass this through I get an error from the linter saying:

`Argument name clash in strict mode`

obviously `amount` has been declared twice

any ideas how I can do this?
 I thought I could do: `amount: someOtherValue` but that still broke

Comment: It works fine for me. At least when `amount` is a previously declared variable.

Comment: What linter is that? Looks fine to me.

Comment: What do you mean saying "declared twice"? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36203366/7404943)?

Comment: yeh my bad, started working for me too now

Comment: @donut mapStateToProps is supposed to be a function that accepts state. This is just an object.

Comment: @lux no this is function that returns an object... im missing the last part, my bad

Comment: @donut You should update your question to reflect the proper code then. You're still showing an object.